# search for words after splitting on delimiter

Tags: grep

I am trying to select all tags having "3" next to a word delimited by /

```
# cat test.txt
test/1,2,3
new/3
one/2,3
more/1,2,4,5
123456/1,2,4,5
```

I can not use simple grep because it will select a word where there is 3 and I am looking for that digit after /

```
# grep '3' test.txt
test/1,2,3
new/3
one/2,3
123456/1,2,4,5
```

This is close, but does not return an entry **"new/3"**

```
# grep '/*,3' test.txt
test/1,2,3
one/2,3
```

What is the correct regular expression for this?

---

Expected output:

```
test/1,2,3
one/2,3
new/3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
grep '/.*\b3\b' test.txt
```

Output:

```
test/1,2,3
new/3
one/2,3
```

> `\b`: a zero-width word boundary

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)